# Sequelize calculate field - VIRTUAL

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following problem.

For example, I have, in a query (Sequalize)

```
const members = await User.findAndCountAll({
    where: {
        id: { [Op.ne]: data_userID}
    }
    offset: data_offset,
    limit: data_offset + 5,
});
```

I must now calculate the age in the query.
The age is stored as DD.MM.YYYYY in the database.
I have found Sequalize VIRTUAL, it seems that I can calculate here

The problem I have is how can I use the AGE as WHERE in VIRTUAL Sequalize?

Like:

```
age: {
      type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
      set: function (val) {
        var birthday_from_database = ...;
        var age = calculate age;

        this.setDataValue('age', age);
     }
```

Am I on the right path?

Answer (score 2):

A virtual field can only be used on the morel instance after the object has been created.

You can’t use them as a constraint clause in a where query.

If you want to querying by age, you can say for exemple, i want all the users that are more than 10 years old, then you can take all the users where the date is greater than or equal to now - INTERVAL ‘10 year’

I hope that will help you

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The issue is, that the greater than or equal (I need both) is saved in a variable as (minAge = 20, maxAge = 29). The Birthday from user is saved as (DD.MM.YYYY) in the database. So I need to calculate in the query WHERE >= and <= .. I have really currently no idea, how I can solve this issue. I have found also Sequalize Validation, maybe I can work with this ?

Comment: If you want a user to be created with that constraint you definitely need a validation. On the age virtual field you can also add a get function that compute the age when you have the user in your hand. Maybe should you have a look on before/after validate hooks instance method if that can help you.